# PHP: Compare Integer/String Variable with Null

Tags: php, string, comparison, integer

I have an Integer/String variable. If I have an error in mysqli statement it becomes **String** and without errors it becomes number of [affected rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) (**Integer**).

But in PHP if we have something like this:

```
$i = 0;
if ( $i < 0 || $i == null ) {
    var_dump($i);
}
```

We have this result:

```
int 0
```

*First*, I want to know why this happens? (I mean, if `var_dump` is `int 0`, why the **if** statement doesn't work?)

*Second*, I want the solution for my comparison.

Comment: Because `0` is considered empty (`NULL`)

Comment: use type safe comparison: `=== null`

Comment: http://codepad.org/dWmodFRs

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski excellent example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't doing a strict comparison.
Use `===` instead of `==`.

`==` will convert types and then compare

Use one of the below instead. [`is_null`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) is the cleanest IMO.

```
if ( $i < 0 || $i === null ) {..}
```

OR

```
if ( $i < 0 || is_null($i)) {..}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing if `0 == null` are equal, not [identical](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), which is the same according to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> ```
> "" (an empty string)
> 0 (0 as an integer)
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
> "0" (0 as a string)
> NULL
> FALSE
> array() (an empty array)
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You need to compare types

```
var_dump($i == null); //true
var_dump($i === null); //false
```

You can use

```
$i = 0;
if ( $i < 0 || $i === null ) {
    var_dump($i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you use `==`. And as long as one operand is `null` - then another is implicitly casted to boolean `0` -> `false`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

> bool or null  anything    Convert to bool, FALSE < TRUE

Answer (score 1):

Use the === comparator

`if ( $i < 0 || $i === null ) {
    var_dump($i);
}`

Comment: `comparator` - where did you take such word? :-S It's an "operator", "comparator" is usually a comparison function passed to a sorting functions

Comment: English isn't my first language... I think I just mash `Comparison Operators` into a single word.

Comment: it's actually not about english, but about programming terms

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`is_null()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) function.

```
if ( $i < 0 || is_null($i) ) {
```